# Write entire column to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, post

I'm trying to write an entire column to a mysql database with values from a form.

I have 1 database filled with products, the prices the stocks etc., and now i want to update all the stocks at the same time in a form.

[Picture from the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LDjC.png)

I have a table, filled with all the data from the database, but i can't write all the _POST fields to the database.

Can anyone help me starting this?

`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY ID ASC';
$resultaat=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultaat))
    {    
    $productnaam= $row['Name'];
    $productid= $row['ID'];
    $productprijs= $row['Price'];
    $voorraad = $row['InStock'];
    $gewenstevoorraad = $row['MinStock'];
    $nodig = ($gewenstevoorraad - $voorraad);
    //De tabel zelf
    echo '
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td><b>'.$productid.'</b></td>
            <td><b><a href="productedit.php?id='.$productid.'">'.$productnaam.'</a></b></td>
            <td class="center"><input type="text" size="3" name="InStock" value="'.$voorraad.'"></td>
            <td class="center">'.$gewenstevoorraad.'</td>
            <td class="center"><b>'.$nodig.'</b></td>
            </tr> ';    
}

    echo '<tr>'."\n" ;
        echo '<td colspan=2><center><input  type="Submit" name="verstuurd" class="btn btn-success" value="Update">'."\n" ;
        echo '  </td>'."\n" ;
    echo '</tr>'."\n" ;
    echo '</form>'."\n" ;`

Comment: so, where's the opening `<form>`? and are you not checking for errors? what problem are you having?

Comment: I'm curious what you are asking for exactly also.

Comment: It's not really a form though, i just don't know the right way to update ALL the data. Error handling is for the later stadium. First i want this to work, with the right UPDATE query. At this point i'm not writing anything to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have a form with fields, which you fill. Submit your form and all that data must be writen to your database?Or you need to update existing rows in your Db?

Comment: I need to update all the existing rows in the database. It's not really a form though.

Comment: You want to load data from database to the form, change your data in form and update it in your database?If yes i can write you an example

Comment: That's exactly what i want. I know how to read and write data from and to the database, but not how to write a whole column on different rows with different values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I load data from DB to a table in `index.php`code:

```
  table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpading='2' width='300 px' align='center'>
    <tr>
        <td>user ID</td><td><input type="text" id="userID" value="<?php echo $row["userID"]?>" disabled/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>user name</td><td><input type="text" id="userName" value="<?php echo $row["userName"] ?>" disabled class="changer"/></td><input type="button" id="changeName" value="changeName"/>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="button" id="confirmButton" value="confirm">
```

I loaded data to table.I disabled the data editing.I have button with id `changeName`, with this button I enabling the editing of username row.
new user name is posted to page `phpTest.php`, where I have update user name query.
Here is some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#changeName').click(function(){

$("#userName").removeAttr("disabled");

$(".changer").change(function(){

var newName=$("#userName").val();
var userID=$("#userID").val();
  $("#confirmButton").click(function(){

jQuery.ajax({

  url:"phpTest.php",
  data:{newName,userID},
  type:"POST",
  success: function(data){

    $("#userInfo").html(data);
  }
});
});
}); 
});
});
```

Query for seting new user name in `phpTest.php` code:

```
if(isset($_POST["newName"])){

$newName=$_POST["newName"];


$stmtChangeName=$user_home->runQuery("UPDATE users SET userName =:newName
    WHERE userID =$userID");
$stmtChangeName->bindParam(":newName", $newName);
if($stmtChangeName->execute()){
    echo "Your name was changed";
}
}
```

After reloading `index.php` you will see that the username was changed.If you have questions, feel free to ask.